# Why for functions such printf standard output is specified as the destination where data goes?

Tags: c

Why for functions such `printf` standard output is specified as the destination where data goes? I mean that there are many IO functions in C standard library which write data to standard output and usually there are corresponding functions like `fprintf` where you can specify where your data goes. Why are there placed these "print always to stdout" functions in C standard library together with functions where you can specify destination? Was it done just for convenience?

Comment: Every process gets the `file descriptors` for `stdin,stdout, stderr` by default, so you could just read/write to them without having to open the `FILE stream` explicitly. convenience! :)

Comment: fprintf()/printf() and friends follow the idea of ixish systems that everything is a file. So the comments that printf() is essentially a shortcut to fprintf(stdout, ...) are correct and that is basically _the_ UNIX idea.
However, I could very well imagine that the inventors of C thought of systems where this is not the case and console output would need to go a completely different path than file I/O. 40 years ago, this UNIX idea was pretty new and may be they thought they'd need something else (a shortcut) for (at that time) "standard" systems.

Comment: "Was it done just for convenience?" Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf` and `scanf` exist because of the widespread use of stdout and stdin (like in console programs). So yes, it is more or less just for convenience.

Generally speaking you would use `fprintf` and `fscanf` for user defined streams.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `printf` function seems to have been defined **in the ANSI C specification** [exactly like so](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/programming/ansic-library.html#stdio):

> `printf(f, ...)` is equivalent to `fprintf(stdout, f, ...)`

If the point of your question is about *why* the decision of making `printf` primarily print to standard input and not another stream, well, I see no discussion about it in the standard.

Implementation-wise, the usual fundamental difference between `fprintf(stdout, f, ...)` and `fprintf(stderr, f, ...)` is that printing to `stderr` will *usually* print output on text console, immediately (one character at a time); whereas the output to `stdout` is **buffered** (printing a `\n` forces the buffer to be printed).

Printing to standard output is thus more efficient (less system calls), and this alone could be a valid reason for `printf` to have been defined that way.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Standard output is buffered.");
    fprintf(stderr, "Standard error is not (this sentence will be printed first). ");
    printf("\n");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Output:

```
Standard error is not (this sentence will be printed first). Standard output is buffered.
```

Comment: @Ingo Oh yes, thanks (edited). I meant that `stderr, [by convention/habit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29), often is "guaranteed" to be unbuffered and outputing to a text terminal.

Comment: @Diti: Then please correct your answer; acknowledging the error in a comment isn't enough.